# SwiftUI - Updating @State when Global changes

Tags: swiftui

I'd like to update an UI element on an overview view when data on another view is changed.

I looked into @EnvironmentalObject and @Binding. However, an update to either object does not appear to force a view reload. Only changes to @State force renders.
Also, in the case described below, the ChangeView is not a child of OverviewView. Therefore @Binding is not an option anyway.

Data.swift

```swift
struct ExampleData : Hashable {
 var id: UUID
 var name: String
}

var globalVar: ExampleData = ExampleData(id: UUID(), name:"")
```

OverviewView.swift

```swift
struct OverviewView: View {
    @State private var data: ExampleData = globalVar
    var body: some View {
       Text(data.name)
    }
}
```

ChangeView.swift

```swift
struct ChangeView: View {
    @State private var data: ExampleData = globalVar
    var body: some View {
       TextField("Name", text: $data.name, onEditingChanged: { _ in 
          globalVar = data }, onCommit: { globalVar = data })
    }
}
```

Changes within the ChangeView TextField will update the globalVar. However, this will not update the Text on the OverviewView when switching back to the view.

I am aware that using global variables is "ugly" coding.  How do I handle data that will be used in a multitude of unrelated views?

Please advise on how to better handle such a situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OverviewView` and `ChangeView` hold different copies of the ExampleData struct in their `data` variables (When assigning a struct to another variable, you're effectively copying it instead of referencing it like an object.) so changing one won't affect the other.

@EnvironmentObject suits your requirements.

Here's an example:
Since, we're using @EnvironmentObject, you need to either convert `ExampleData` to 
a class, or use a class to store it. I'll use the latter.

```
class ExampleDataHolder: ObservableObject {
    @Published var data: ExampleData = ExampleData(id: UUID(), name:"")
}

struct CommonAncestorOfTheViews: View {
    var body: some View {
       CommonAncestorView()
          .environmentObject(ExampleDataHolder())
    }
}

struct OverviewView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var dataHolder: ExampleDataHolder

    var body: some View {
       Text(dataHolder.data.name)
    }
}

struct ChangeView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var dataHolder: ExampleDataHolder

    var body: some View {
       TextField("Name", text: $dataHolder.data.name)
    }
}
```